# Reinstating deleted built-in site columns SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, site-column

On removing two built-in site columns from a custom content type they appear to have been deleted from the site collection.  I find it surprising that they are deleted as they are in use in many sub sites in this site collection and they were only being removed from the content type.  How do we go about reinstating these 2 site columns.  They are the "Assign To" and "Due Date" columns.  Consequently that are also removed from the task content type.  This has occurred on SharePoint online.
Any help much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to open a support ticket with Microsoft. They can reinstate it from the back end.

Comment: Can you recommend someone to talk to about this as we have had a support call logged and Microsoft do not appear to understand the problem after many hours on the phone.

Comment: I would ask to escalate since they do not seem to understand the ask. Support communicates with the product group to get this information/approval.